# Failed to connect to repository - 401 on Jenkins + Codebase Git

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to get Jenkins to use Git as our SCM, and setting it up is being a bit of a pain.

When specifying the Codebase Git repo to use, using the following format:

```
https://our.domain.com/repository/repository.git
```

I get the following error from Jenkins:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Failed to connect to https://our.domain.com/repository/repository.git (status = 401)
```

The repository is private, and I'm not sure how to configure a user account for it. I've generated a RSA SSH key for the Jenkins user, on my Ubuntu server, and added this to Codebase as a deployment key.

I keep on getting the 404 error?

Also, if I try the

```
git@codebasehq.com:.../repository.git
```

format, I just get a different error from Jenkins:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "ls-remote -h git@codebasehq.com:.../repository.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 6):

I am late but In future this will help to other people

insted of

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

replace this

```
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

in the Git Repository URL

Comment: perfectly working !!! kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! You need to got to Jenkins / Credentials, add the credentials account there, and then select these credentials when adding the SCM Git stuff.